# How to delay the Windows 10 login screen until a startup task has finished

Tags: windows, windows-10, startup

We need to run and finish a process before the Windows login shows. This may take several minutes.  Windows updates often seem to be doing exactly what we need. When you reboot the machine they finish the install and only after that the login screen shows.

I know I can create a Windows service or a scheduled task at system startup but these options can't delay the login screen  until they are finished.

I hope this makes sense. Does anybody know how to do this? I have spent a lot of time searching for solutions but can't find anything.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It sounds like what you want is to block the user from logging into the desktop - not actually block the login screen?  More details please...

Comment: Yes, we don't want the user to be able to login while our task hasn't finished

Comment: Add: Windows Update often shows a screen "Updating" after it reboots and only shows the login screen after the update has finished. Ideally we would like do the same thing for our process but I can't find any information how this could be accomplished.

Comment: Any updates? Have you succeeded with this mission? I'm currently looking for an answer to this exact same problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question?

Comment: No solution found. We got in touch with someone from MS and they said maybe a custom login screen would work. But that's a different beast in terms of complexity.